# How to store output of a stored procedure on to disk

Tags: stored-procedures, file-io

We are using SQL Server 2005.
I want to create the file of the output of the stored procedure.

Comment: which language? any particular format? what operating system?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MySQL you may want to start from the following:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE export_dynamic(IN file_path char(64))
BEGIN
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * INTO OUTFILE ', 
                      "'", file_path, "'", ' FROM Table1');

    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Borrowed from: [MySQL Forums :: General :: SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE not possible with stored procedure parameters?](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,90709,93744#msg-93744)

If you want to hardcode the filename in the stored procedure, then there is no need to use a prepared statement:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE export_static()
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/file_name.txt' FROM Table1;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

If you get a `Can't create/write to file` error, make sure to check the following reference: [MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual :: Can't create/write to file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cannot-create.html).