# Pass Windows path to MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, windows, path

I have a stored procedure based on this question: [How to store output of a stored procedure on to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333806/how-to-store-output-of-a-stored-procedure-on-to-disk). For some reason I can't make it work with a Windows path. Always get the file writing error.

Any idea on how to pass the parameter?

Comment: It could be something to do with permission. Can you give the dest folder with the permission 777 and try once(just to make sure if its permission thing)

Answer (score 2):

Just tried this and struggled a bit too. Here's how I got it working:

1. On the folder(s) where MySQL will write files, make sure the appropriate privileges are given for write access. *If security isn't a concern, a brute-force way of doing this is to right-click on the root folder, click on Properties -> Security tab, add "Everyone" and grant "Full Control". However, depending on where and why you are doing this you might need to be a lot more careful/selective...*
2. Run the stored proc using something like:

   `CALL export_dynamic('C:/dump/test1.txt');`

   ...or...

   `CALL export_dynamic('C:\\\\dump\\\\test2.txt');`

   (assuming `C:\dump` is the folder where files will be written with the permissions set as above.)

Note: There are other possible issues with disk space, anti-virus etc. but personally I didn't see anything like that (have Microsoft Security Essentials running).

Answer (score 1):

The file name must be given as a literal string. On Windows, specify backslashes in path names as forward slashes or doubled backslashes.

As of MySQL 5.1.6, the character_set_filesystem system variable controls the interpretation of the file name.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a permission issue... Check the folder permissions of the folder you are trying to write. Grant access to everyone.. Right Click on folder -> Properties -> Permissions -> Everyone -> Give full rights... now run the script.